# CoroutineExceptionHandler and try-catch not catching exceptions in Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm working with Kotlin Coroutines and encountered an issue where neither my `CoroutineExceptionHandler` nor the `try-catch` block seem to catch exceptions thrown within an async block. Below is the simplified code snippet to demonstrate the issue:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun log(message: String) {
    println("[${Thread.currentThread()}] $message")
}

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
        println("Caught $exception")
    }
    val scope = CoroutineScope(handler)
    val task = scope.async() {
        log("throw exception")
        throw RuntimeException("Exception")
    }
    scope.launch(handler) {
        try {
            task.await()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            log("catch exception: ${e.message}")
        }
        delay(1000)
        log("finish await")
    }
    delay(2000)
}
```

When I run this code, I expect the CoroutineExceptionHandler or the try-catch block to catch the exception thrown inside the async block, but neither of them seems to work. The exception isn't caught, and neither of my log messages indicating an exception ("Caught $exception" or "catch exception: ${e.message}") are printed out. Instead, the program ends without any indication of the exception being caught or handled.

Could someone explain why the exception handling isn't working as expected in this case? Is there something wrong with how I've set up the CoroutineExceptionHandler or the way I'm using try-catch with await()? Any insights or suggestions on how to properly catch exceptions in this context would be greatly appreciated.

### Update 1

The console log output:

```
[Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1,5,main]] throw exception
```

Comment: First of all, these coroutines don't even have a chance to start executing, because you immediately finish the application. Please add `delay()` at the end to check if this is not the problem you observe. I tried to reproduce your observations using Playground, but actually I see a log there, so most probably, this is in fact just a race condition between launching coroutines and finishing the app.

Comment: @broot I just updated my question and put the console output. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest changing your main line to `suspend fun main() = coroutineScope {` so it joins all jobs you launch.

Comment: @Pawel It won't join them, because OP used a separate scope for launching jobs. I don't even go into details if this is required or not. This is just a minimal reproducible example, so it doesn't have to meet best practices :-)

Comment: @broot right, m bad. I recommend OP reads the [exception handling doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exception-handling.html#coroutineexceptionhandler). TLDR: `async` catches exceptions in `Deferred` object so exception handler never works on them.